# Which method in the view call hierarchy is best to hide a subview

Tags: ios, view

I need to have my view invisible once the view appears. I do make modifications to its layer's anchor points and its frame. I found that adding the code in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will override the changes as I found it gets called multiple times. I am currently placing the frame and anchor point changes inside the `viewWillAppear` but sometimes you can see the view change size at the beginning. So is there a method that gets called after `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and before the view appears and is only called once so I could perform my changes. Or if you have other suggestions as to how to approach this i'd be open to hear.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a view it is simple :

```
view.hidden = true
```

OR

```
view.alpha = 0.0 //hidden, value 1.0 is totally visible
```

In `viewDidLoad`

- you are sure you will not see the view to hiding (already hidden before view is visible).

Avoid `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

- it could occurs, for example, any time a view needs layout : `view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Well I want my view to animate between a zero frame rect and its original size so setting alpha is probably not a good solution

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand what you want to do. You didn't talk about animation. Maybe if you show a bit of code it will be easier to help you.